# Adding sleep time in a bash command for each pod deletion

Tags: bash

I have the following bash command:

```
oc get pods -o wide \
    | grep -v asm \
    | grep -v fnd \
    | grep -v key \
    | grep -v apiwg \
    | grep -v cbkc \
    | grep -v container \
    | grep -v apigw \
    | grep -v apacheds \
    | grep -v couchbase-service \
    | grep -v catalogone-tool-job \
    | grep -v connector \
    | grep -v operator \
    | grep -v broker \
    | grep -v logicaldate \
    | grep -v oc-audit \
    | grep -v oc-cb-01-000 \
    | grep -v light-tracer \
    | grep -v rule-engine \
    | awk '{print $1}' \
    | grep -v NAME \
    | xargs oc delete pod --force --grace-period=0
```

I'm trying to trigger a sleep timer for each pod deletion (`xargs oc delete pod`), what are my options?

Comment: Please format your code as code, note as blockquotes that do not preserve the formatting.

Comment: Ok, formatted as code

Comment: You know, `xargs` passes a number of its input words to the command, not just one. So your pods are deleted by batches. Maybe all by one single `oc delete pod` command, if the list fits in the maximum allowed length. Do you want a sleep after each single deletion or after each group of deletions that `xargs oc delete...` performs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `xargs` is the appropriate tool if you want to delete one by one.  `xargs` is designed to process arguments in batches.  If executing `oc delete pod ...` one by one is acceptable, you could pass  `-n 1`, but then you might as well use a for loop.  On top of that you have so many unnecessary calls to grep.  I would do something like this:

```
declare -a PODS=$(
  oc get pods -o wide | grep -v \
    -e asm \
    -e fnd \
    -e key \
    -e apiwg \
    -e cbkc \
    -e container \
    -e apigw \
    -e apacheds \
    -e couchbase-service \
    -e catalogone-tool-job \
    -e connector \
    -e operator \
    -e broker \
    -e logicaldate \
    -e oc-audit \
    -e oc-cb-01-000 \
    -e light-tracer \
    -e rule-engine | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v NAME
)

for i in "${PODS[@]}"; do
    oc delete pod --force --grace-period=0 "$i"
    sleep 10
done
```

**EDIT:** Since the OP asked for it to be one command; you can just replace the `PODS` array with the command on the top like this:

```
for i in "$(oc get pods -o wide | ... )"; do
    oc delete pod --force --grace-period=0 "$i";
    sleep 10;
done
```

You can also use a for loop interactively, there's no limitation, you just need to add the semicolons to denote the end of a command, and type everything in one line.  Note the quoted subshell: `"$(...)"`.  Keeping this is important in case you have containers with spaces in their names (thanks to @RenaudPacalet for that improvement).

Comment: You forgot `"$i"` at the end of the delete command.

Comment: ...and you should probably double-quote `${PODS[@]}` and `$i`, just in case there are spaces in these pod names.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thanks again!  I wasn't sure about `${PODS[@]}`, but a quick expt confirmed it, I guess without the quotes the shell expands it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to execute this script as one command?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a sleep to the command you pass to `xargs` e.g. by wrapping it in `sh -c ...`.

That's some horrible pipeline stringing, by the way.  You can refactor `grep -v foo | grep -v bar` to `grep -v -e foo -e bar` or save the strings in a file and use `grep -v -f filename`; but let's further refactor everything into a single Awk script. See also [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

```sh
oc get pods -o wide |
awk '!/asm|fnd|key|apiwg|cbkc|container|apigw|apacheds|couchbase-service|catalogone-tool-job|connector|operator|broker|logicaldate|oc-audit|oc-cb-01-000|light-tracer|rule-engine/ && $1 !~ /NAME/ {
   print $1}' |
xargs sh -c 'for f; do
    oc delete pod --force --grace-period=0 "$f"
    sleep 1
done' _
```

The Awk script could probably be refactored further to pass in the strings as an array or something, but that also depends on where exactly these strings come from.  Sounds like maybe you should add a tag or something so you can add an argument to `oc get pods` to target just the ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop it normally - there's no reason to use xargs. Here's another take:

```
exclude=(
   asm
   fnd
   ...
)

oc get pods -o wide |
grep -v -f <(printf "%s\n" "${exclude[@]}") |
awk '{print $1}' |
grep -v NAME |
while IFS= read -r f; do
   oc delete pod --force --grace-period=0 "$f"
   sleep 1
done
```

When you put `|` on the end of lines, then there's no need to write `\`.

Comment: Deleted my answer as yours is much superior in every way.

Comment: With a `sleep 1` in the picture, performance is probably not an issue. But all these `grep` in a pipe containing also an `awk`...